# UITableViewController table won't refresh after deletion, but will refresh on viewWillAppear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a button for each cell, and once clicked it deletes each individual object from the Parse backend. I have it set to `reloadData` upon success in the block as seen here:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    PFRelation *relation = [self.currentUser relationforKey:@"watching"];
    [[relation query] findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
            // There was an error
            } else {
               // NSLog(@"%@", objects);
                self.watchingEvents = objects;
                [self refreshTableView];
            }
    }];
}

-(IBAction) deleteButtonAction:(id) sender
{
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Removing from Watch List..."];

    PFRelation *relation = [self.currentUser relationforKey:@"watching"];
    [relation removeObject:self.selectedEvent];
    [self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (error)
        {
            NSString *errorString = [[error userInfo] objectForKey:@"error"];
            UIAlertView *errorAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [errorAlertView show];
        }
        else
        {
            [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Removed from Watch List!"];
            [self refreshTableView];
        }
    }];
}
-(void)refreshTableView
{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But it doesn't seem to update the tableView, the cell still shows up (even though it's gone because if I navigate away and open the view again the `viewWillAppear` gets called with the same `reloadData` function and the items gone like how it should be. So I know the functions working, since it's clearly working in `viewWillAppear`. Not sure why it's not working once the success of the block is run, as the alert runs fine as does any NSLog message I put in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are deleting the data from the backend but you are not deleting that object from self.watchingEvents. and i think u must be using self.watchingEvents to populate the date in cellForRowAtindex of your table. Please delete that object from self.watchingEvents too on deletion and your problem should be solved.

Comment: It is my guess that u are populating your table from self.watchingEvents. If not please show your cellForRowAtIndex method for debugging.

Comment: It is working on ViewWillAppear because u update self.watchingEvents with the data present in the backend, So when you delete an object and do ViewWillAppear, self.watchingEvents gets updated from the backend(which now does not have the deleted object). Thus you get the correct data in the table.

Comment: Hrm not sure how I would fix it then, you are correct I am using [self.watchingEvents count] for populating the table. I just figured when I'm calling [self.tableView reloadData] that it's refreshing the table, therefore checking the [self.watchingEvents count] again, no?

Comment: Think I fixed it by changing array to NSMutableArray and simply calling [self.watchingEvents removeObject:self.selectedEvent]; , Thanks!

Comment: It seems to work but now I get  warning saying Incompatible pointer types assigning to NSMutableArray from NSArray in the viewWillAppear. I can see what it's talking about but how would I fix this? I can't change NSArray to NSmutableArray without getting an error, and if I change it back to NSArray it won't allow me to removeObject considering it's no longer NSMutable ----- Edit: Fixed it by changing it to self.watchingEvents = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:objects];

Comment: while deleting the object you need to delete it from self.watchingEvents and your backend. :) And yes you are right. self.watchingEvents has to be a NSMutableArray as we cannot edit NSArray.

Answer (score 1):

Change you refresh method to:

```
-(void)refreshTableView
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [tableView beginUpdates] before you do delete, insert or move actions and then [tableView endUpdates] at the end.

```
- (void)beginUpdates;
- (void)endUpdates;
```

https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/beginUpdates